# Check the characters inside two strings are the same in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two strings, `a` and `b`, in Ruby.

```
a="scar"
b="cars"
```

What is the easiest way in Ruby to find whether `a` and `b` contain the same characters?

**UPDATE**
I am building an Anagram game ,so scar is an anagram of cars.So i want a way to compare a and b and come to conclusion that its an anagram
So `c="carcass"` should not be a match

Comment: How do you want to deal with repeated characters? e.g. `c = "carcass"`, is that a match to a and b? In fact, do you want a `true/false` response at all, or the intersection. Could you give example output in code rather than the ambiguous "it should say"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9646995/1301972 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/16631961/1301972, or answered by one of their answers.

Comment: @CodeGnome Exactly what I was looking for.Actually I was trying manually create hash when group_by was already there. Ruby roxx!!

Comment: Should `a` and `b` is always same size? Can `a` can contain duplicate characters? in that case what result you would expect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
a = 'scar'
b = 'cars'
a.chars.sort == b.chars.sort
# => true

a = 'cars'
b = 'carcass'
a.chars.sort == b.chars.sort
# => false
```

Comment: I think `a.chars.sort.join == b.chars.sort.join` is better because comparation of arrays is more time consuming than comparation of strings. Just a note ;)

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev But this is not inequality; it is equality. The moment the two arrays include different elements, the comparison will terminate. And `join` is an extra operation. Do you have numerical basis for your claim?

Answer (score 9):

Just for testing arrays vs string vs delete comparation. Assuming we compare strings with equal length.

In the real anagram search you need to sort first word `a` once. And then compare it to bunch of b's.

```
a="scar"
b="cars"

require 'benchmark'

n = 1000000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('string') { a = a.chars.sort.join; n.times do ; a == b.chars.sort.join ; end }
  x.report('arrays') { a = a.chars.sort; n.times do ; a == b.chars.sort ; end }
end
```

The result:

```
          user     system      total        real
string  6.030000   0.010000   6.040000 (  6.061088)
arrays  6.420000   0.010000   6.430000 (  6.473158)
```

But, if you sort `a` each time (for `delete` we don't need to sort any word):

```
x.report('string') { n.times do ; a.chars.sort.join == b.chars.sort.join ; end }
x.report('arrays') { n.times do ; a.chars.sort == b.chars.sort ; end }
x.report('delete') { n.times do ; a.delete(b).empty? ; end }
```

The result is:

```
          user     system      total        real
string 11.800000   0.020000  11.820000 ( 11.989071)
arrays 11.210000   0.020000  11.230000 ( 11.263627)
delete  1.680000   0.000000   1.680000 (  1.673979)
```

Comment: Inserted your variant in the second benchmar. For first benchmark it is the same. It's incredible faster ;) Need to investigate the algoritm of `delete` then...

Comment: `delete` doesn't doesn't deal with duplicates correctly anyway

Answer (score 3):

> What is the easiest way in Ruby to find whether a and b contain the same characters?

As per the definitions of [**Anagram**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram) the below written code should work :

```
a="scar"
b="cars"
a.size == b.size && a.delete(b).empty?
```

Comment: You should be sure that length of both strings are the same, otherwise `a="scar"` and `b="carse"` returns `true` in your code.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev Yes.. That OP didn't put..It would fail if the string doesn't have same length..OP said only to test if they contain same charters or not.. that's it.

Comment: But for real world, when you search for anagram, it works, because you can skip words with different length before comparation. So -- +1 :)

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev so how this would be `a.size == b.size && a.delete(b).empty?`

Comment: This won't work for duplicate letters, eg "abb" and "baa"

Answer (score 1):

`require 'set'
Set.new(a.chars) == Set.new(b.chars)`

updated to take into account comment from sawa

Comment: When your answer depends on a library, do not omit that.

Comment: This will not handle words with duplicated letters, since a set would discard them.

Comment: @CodeGnome That requirement was added after this answer was posted. The original question mentioned (and the present one still mentions) "whether `a` and `b` contain the same characters".