# Not able to solve anagram by group?

Tags: ruby, hash, rspec, group-by, anagram

I have already read all the answers to similar questions but I still cannot get it to work for me.

This is the code I wrote for finding and grouping an anagram for the sentence:

```
"scream cars for four scar creams"
```

The expected output is:

```
OUTPUT: ["cars", "scar"]

def anagram_groups
 result = []
   here = self.gsub(/\W/," ").downcase.split(" ")
   here = self.split(" ")
   here.each do |y|
     #result == here.group_by{|w| w.chars.sort}.values
      result == here.select {|x| x.chars.sort == y.chars.sort}
   end
 result
end
```

I tried two different methods but neither of them seem to work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I simplify or clean up this anagram method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631961/how-can-i-simplify-or-clean-up-this-anagram-method)

Comment: Your expected result is an array including words, but what do you expect when there are more than one group of words that are anagrams to one another? Question is not clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how you can do it :

```
str = "scream cars for four scar creams"
str.split.group_by{|a| a.chars.sort}.select{|k,v| v.size > 1 }.values
# => [["scream", "creams"], ["cars", "scar"]]
```

Comment: @Arup can you please explain the code? As I am new to ruby and can you please also tell me the errors in my code?

Comment: Also, I thought that you should know this that I am doing it as a homework and I have to check the output using rspec code given to me, and I am still getting an error even after using your code. Thanks

Comment: @Rohit That might be,you did something wrong in your rspec code..But regarding the above answer,would you tell me which part is not being understood... I will help you in that point...Let me know that.

Comment: @ArupRakshit the rspec code was provided to me by the professors so I am sure it is correct. And I googled around and now I understand your code. But I don't know why I can't get it to work for me. Can you tell me if the code that I had written earlier was wrong or not? Maybe I am implementing it wrong:  this is the error I am getting if it helps:   1) anagram grouping for "scream cars for four scar creams"
    `Failure/Error: @anagrams.should include(group)
    expected [] to include ["cars", "scar"]
    Diff:
    @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
    -["cars", "scar"]
    +[]`